# How to check port opened on running a service?

Tags: linux, networking, command-line, services

Let's say I started a service by using `sudo service service_name start`, I am interested in knowing all the port opened by this service. I can know port - program mapping  by `sudo netstat -tulnp` but I need to know for a  specific service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this, I usually use `lsof` with the option to show the ports in use.

Here's an example:

```
[root@localhost ~]# lsof -Pi | grep myprog
myprog  23411  user    9u  IPv6 9828537      0t0  TCP 1.2.3.167:51163->1.2.3.54:8090 (ESTABLISHED)
myprog  23411  user   16u  IPv4 9827813      0t0  TCP 1.2.3.167:60783->1.2.3.186:23 (ESTABLISHED)
myprog  23411  user   23u  IPv4 9827817      0t0  TCP 192.168.2.8:37435->192.168.2.1:20003 (ESTABLISHED)
myprog  23411  user   24u  IPv4 9827815      0t0  TCP 192.168.2.8:38942->192.168.2.1:20001 (ESTABLISHED)
myprog  23411  user   30u  IPv4 9849168      0t0  TCP 1.2.3.167:52352 (LISTEN)
myprog  23411  user   31u  IPv4 9849242      0t0  TCP 1.2.3.167:52352->1.2.3.186:59323 (ESTABLISHED)
myprog  23411  user   33u  IPv4 9852370      0t0  TCP 1.2.3.167:40328 (LISTEN)
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Answer (score 0):

You can kill the process directly using `sudo fuser -k 80/tcp` (replace port with whatever you need)