# is there a way to map a port to an application or service?

Tags: linux, networking, command-line, services

when I run something like -

```
# ss -atur
```

I get lot of replies of opened ports such as -

```
udp    UNCONN     0       0                0.0.0.0:631                                          0.0.0.0:*                
udp    UNCONN     0       0                0.0.0.0:mdns                                         0.0.0.0:*                
udp    UNCONN     0       0                0.0.0.0:38350                                        0.0.0.0:*
```

now while I know that 631 is used by CUPS, have no idea what these other ports are being used for. Is there a way to get the ports known to the application which used them, a kind of reverse-mapping. I am more concerned about local ports being open without a legitimate use. Please let me know if any more info. is needed. I am on Debian testing.

I even tried lsof but with no luck -

[How to check port opened on running a service?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/350490/how-to-check-port-opened-on-running-a-service)

I am using lsof 4.93.2 in case if that makes any difference.

For e.g. I tried -

```
 root@debian:~# lsof -Pi | grep qbittorrent
    root@debian:~#
```

Now I know that qbittorrent would need to open up at least a few local ports in order to accept data and similarly would be opening up local ports but don't see anything :(

Comment: Does your version of the `ss` command have the `-p` option? It will map each listed port to a process ID.

Comment: it does, thank you for sharing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`ss` command](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ss) provides an option to map ports to their corresponding processes:

> `-p`, `--processes`
>
> Show process using socket.

The output will then contain an additional column, which maps each listed port to a specific process ID.